# Libgdx nine patch text button height issue

Tags: java, libgdx, nine-patch

I am using a `TextButton` to create a dialog bubble effect in my game.
I have created the nine patch file as on the picture
[image]
everything seems to be fine until I try to use this bubble.9 with LibGDX, the `TextButton` is not stretching correctly based on the text height.

[image]

[image]

You can see that a multilines text extends the `TextButton` height but not correctly.

Here is the code

Load the bitmap font

```
FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));
FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter dialogFont = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
dialogFont.fontFileName = Conf.ASSET_FONT;
dialogFont.fontParameters.size = 8;
```

Initialize the `TextButtonStyle`

```
NinePatch patch = atlas.createPatch("bubble");
NinePatchDrawable dialogBoxPatch = new NinePatchDrawable(patch);
buttonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
buttonStyle.up = dialogBoxPatch;
buttonStyle.down = dialogBoxPatch;
buttonStyle.checked = dialogBoxPatch;
buttonStyle.over = dialogBoxPatch;
buttonStyle.font = dialogFont;
buttonStyle.fontColor = Color.BLACK;
```

actual rendering

```
dialogBox = new TextButton("some\ntext", buttonStyle);
dialogBox.draw(batch, 1);
```

Does someone see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
I have decided to test the ninepatch with another font and it worked like a charm. To understand what was going on, I have opened the two fonts with [glyphrstudio](http://www.glyphrstudio.com/). It appears that the problematic font is not correctly designed.

Bad font

[image]

Good font

[image]

You can see that the base line and capheight are not correctly setted on the bad font.

I hope this will help other people facing the same problem.